# Show Submenu on Hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm working on a project where I've got to create a nav menu with selectable submenus that show up on hover. Please refer to image below:

[image: Nav Menu]

I've got the About portion to show on hover, but I need it to stay such that the submenu items can be selected. Also, I need other sections to have nested areas as well.

I've made a `codepen` project for this [HERE](https://codepen.io/RvnSln/pen/eYvrdGw)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can you please create a React sandbox and put a link? Not able to get this recreated

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I've put this into a codepen sandbox. Thanks for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 0):

Not really a plug and play solution from my side, just a useful hint, but how about you also run the first menu open function on the child menu, and also on the grand-child menu. That way it will stay open during the whole menu interaction. Cheers!

Comment: I've made a codepen out of this. Would you be able to show me what you mean on there if its not too much trouble? Thank you!

Comment: Hey! Sorry for late reply. I was thinking like this:

Comment: let subMenu = document.querySelector('.submenu-items');
subMenu.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
  subMenu.classlist.add('active');
});
subMenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
  subMenu.classlist.remove('active');
});

Comment: I am new to react but quite crafty in vanilla JS so if you can understand me it would be great! Cheers!